# HttpHeaders set (or apply) overwrites headers

Tags: angular6, angular-httpclient

Migrating Angular4 app to Angular6 and noticed, headers are not applied:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set('email', this.email); // or headers.apply
```

later - `headers.keys() //=> []`

But if overriten on every `set()`, it works:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers = headers.set('email', this.seedrsEmail);
```

And as from `@angular/common/http` headers are immutable, how should I append new headers in Interceptor?

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  req.headers.append('user_token', '1234') // overwrites headers
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way i found was to add every header separetly. Please feel free to propose a better way:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler):
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

  let newHeaders: HttpHeaders = req.headers;
  newHeaders = newHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  newHeaders = newHeaders.set('user_token', '6547')
  newHeaders = newHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  newHeaders = newHeaders.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

  let newReq = req.clone({headers: newHeaders});

  return next.handle(newReq);
```